# How to call localhost/magento/oauth/initiate?

Tags: api, soap, rest-api, oauth

I am trying to call the above url to initiate the oauth tokens. 
I am following the below link **http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/authentication/oauth_authentication.html**
Can u tell me what s the exact way to call the initiate url . 
By the way , I am using oAuth Advanced rest client.

Comment: visit:-https://gist.github.com/mathewka/10704227

Comment: I am trying using a rest client. By adding headers and parameters. No code and all.

Comment: Ashvin , When I tried your link,
http://localhost/magento/admin/oauth_authorize?oauth_token=&oauth_callback=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmagento%2Fapi%2Frest%2Fproducts
the controller redirects to above url and I am getting this following error

An error occurred. Your authorization request is invalid.